# Change top padding of nine-patch image after stretching

Tags: android, textview, nine-patch

I have TextView with nine-patch background image:

[image: nine-patch for TextView]

The vertical padding is set to fit text into bottom grey rectangle like this:

[image: good padding]

But when the image is stretched vertically, it's top padding saves its absolute value, so text goes above of expected place:

[image: wrong top padding]

**How to make TextView increase top padding after vertical stretch and fit text into bottom area which is not stretchable?**